# How do I make the title to an open accordion change color?

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have an accordion with several bullets.

I would like the title text to change color when the bullet is opened in the accordion.

Can this be achieved with CSS?

How do I do this?

```
.accordion-toggle:hover  {color:#C04747}
```

How do I make the accordion reamin color changed when opened?

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

     //Expand or collapse this panel
     $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

     //Hide the other panels
     $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `addClass('active')` to append a class to the clicked accordion title.

In your css styles add the class `.active` behind your `:hover` declaration.

**CSS**

```
.accordion-toggle:hover, .accordion-toggle.active  {color:#C04747}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion .accordion-toggle').click(function(){

       //Remove active classes
       $('#accordion .accordion-toggle').removeClass('active');

       //Expand or collapse this panel
       $(this).addClass('active');
       $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

       //Hide the other panels
       $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**

View my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7t6W4/)

Comment: Like this?  .accordion-toggle:active  {color:#C04747}

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I copied and pasted everything but it does not change color.  Here is the page:  http://www.givemehope.com/answers.htm

Comment: change the jquery rules in my anwser. `addClass()` in seperated line.

Comment: also change your selector like this: `$('#accordion .accordion-toggle')`. Their is no need to use `find()`.

Comment: My mistake remove the dot in your jquery script before the active class: `.addClass('active')`

Comment: You can view the result in the jsfiddle I added in my anwser.

Comment: Oh crap.... The color remains red when I click on other bullets.  How do I remove the color red when a bullet is inactive?  Sorry

Comment: Remove the active class on all titles in the beginning. See my anwser!